# Cloud Tasks and the enforced rate

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

We are using Cloud Tasks to call an "on-prem" API gateway (using Http request). This API gateway (IBM API Connect) sits in front off an on-prem system (Oracle). This back end system can at times be very slow. >5s.

We are desperately trying to increase the throughput but “adjusting” the Cloud Task queue settings (like -max-dispatches-per-second etc). 
`gcloud tasks queues update queue-1 --max-dispatches-per-second=8 --max-concurrent-dispatches=16`

But all we see when we “crank up” the Cloud Task settings is that yellow triangle telling us that we are “enforced" to lower rate due to "system resources".

My understanding is that the yellow triangle shows up due to “errors” from the API gateway we call. Basically GCP/Cloud Tasks re-acts "by it self" based on return codes/errors/time-outs/latency etc from the API end-point we are calling with the result of a very low rate/thru-put. Is this understanding correct? Can someone verify?

The GUI does say that "or because currently there is no instance available to execute a request". What instance are they talking about? So to me that means that there is a possibility that it's "GCP specific" resources that comes into the picture here and have an effect on the "enforced rate"? Or?

Anyway, any help/insight would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you are seeing can be prompted by any of the 2 things you are mentioning: "Enforced rates" or "lack of GCP resources at the time of request".

The "Enforced rates" that Cloud tasks is refering to are the ones mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/common-pitfalls#resource_limitations). As you mention, this is due to the server being overloaded and returning too many errors. When this happens Cloud tasks acts by itself and will slow down execution until errors stop.

The "currently there is no instance available to execute a request" message you are seeing is that GCP does not have resources to create the request. Remember that cloud tasks is a managed service so this means that requests are created by GCP fully managed compute engine instances. This is a bit rare, although it does happen from time to time.

In order to make sure which of these 2 issues is the one you are running into, I would recommend you to check your Stackdriver logs and see if you are getting a high amount of errors on the Cloud Tasks filter as if this is the case, most likely you are running into the "Enforced rates" territory.

Hope you find this useful!

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding. The core issue is clearly errors coming back from the API. Tons of 500 errors and timeouts. Running `gcloud tasks list --queue=my-queue` command gave a clear picture. Once again thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help, if you found this useful, please upvote or accept the answer so other members of the community can see it.